# I'm getting SyntaxError: Parser error in a WordPress theme

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I tried many times to fix it but I couldn't find any solution.

My jQuery code is placed in footer.php of a wordpress theme.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($)
    {
        $('input#submit').attr('disabled', true);

        $('input[type="text"], textarea').on('keyup',function()
        {
            var textarea_value = $("#texta").val();
            var text_value = $('input[name="text"]').val();
            var email_value = $('input[name="email"]').val();

            <?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) : ?>
                if(textarea_value != '') {
            <?php else : ?>
                if(textarea_value != '' && text_value != '' && email_value != '') {
            <?php endif; ?>

                $('input#submit').attr('disabled' , false);
            } else {
                $('input#submit"]').attr('disabled' , true);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

the last `});` is giving me this error in console.
Do you have any idea about this issue? Where I'm wrong here?
Thankyou.

Comment: the power of indentation ... you have an extra `});`

Comment: and as an aside, you should never mix PHP with JS - it's really bad practice

Comment: I agree with @treyBake. Its really bad practice to combine both

Answer (score 0):

Its extra `}` causing issue. You have kept `if` condition based on user login, So ending should be only be with 1 brace, But you have added 2 braces instead.

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
          jQuery(document).ready(function($)
    {
        $('input#submit').attr('disabled', true);

        $('input[type="text"], textarea').on('keyup',function()
        {
            var textarea_value = $("#texta").val();
            var text_value = $('input[name="text"]').val();
            var email_value = $('input[name="email"]').val();

            <?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) : ?>
                if(textarea_value != '') {
            <?php else : ?>
                if(textarea_value != '' && text_value != '' && email_value != '') {
            <?php endif; ?>
                $('input#submit').attr('disabled' , false);
            } else {
                $('input#submit"]').attr('disabled' , true);
            }

    });
});
    </script>
```

Comment: typos should be flagged and commented on - not answered :)

Comment: @treyBake. I agree, But its difficult to tell them to remove something from something line

Comment: thanks but this time its giving: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '}'. Expected ')' to end an argument list.`

Comment: So its impossible using php here?

Comment: @AlbanoAlbanese. I have updated my answer. Can you check again?